# broken internal JavaScript and CSS files

Tags: css, javascript

there is more pages like this when i try to open any page i cant see the products and the wp-includes is not in that place i dont know why they trying to access from that path

https://moroccan-craft-suppliers.com/product-category/moroccan-furniture/chairs/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js

Comment: I can see this line in the head: `<link as="script" href="wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" rel="preload">`. Have you attempted to preload jquery recently?

Comment: yes I did but not recently, this happens after I transfer my website from domain to this domain

Comment: How did you do it? You should use the full URL, including the domain, or at least include a `/` at the beginning.

Comment: were using w3 total cache and autoptimize